# Loading language at run time - pushed by Server

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am looking for a way in which I can change the language of my application (only) at runtime. My application communicates with Server and there are various instructions that pushed from Server to the application. Now, there is a need that language of the application should be changed at runtime when server pushes it. Regardless of language that is running on the phone, the application should change to Language that is pushed by the server. I have string.xml for all these languages.

Thanks,
SKU

Comment: THanks Eric, I guess it answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

To change the language of the contain that retrived from the server just add a header "Accept-Language" to your request with the value .

> String languge = can be "fr" for french "an" English
>
> request.addHeader("Accept-Language", languge);